# How to get username from a table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

My Mysql table structure is like this

```
id category name
```

This is the way to show in jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${parentList}" var="test">
<ul style="max-width: 300px;" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="active"><a href="#" value="${test.id}-${test.category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);">
  <input type="checkbox" value="${test.id}">${test.name }</a></li>

    </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

parentList is obtained from the below method

```
List<Parent> parentList = 
                (List<Parent>)  serviceClientServiceImpl.getParents("Parent",Long.valueOf(clientId));
```

this is my `serviceClientServiceImpl.getParents`

```
public List<Parent> getParents(String entityName,Long clientId)
    {
        List<Parent> parentsList = null;
        try
        {
            parentsList = (List<Parent>) serviceClientDaoImpl.getParents(entityName,clientId);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return parentsList;
    }
```

and this is my `serviceClientDaoImpl.getParents`

```
public List<Parent> getParents(String entityName,Long cId)
    {
        String queryString="";
        queryString="select p FROM "+entityName+"p WHERE category=default or category=client and p.cid="+cId;
        Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("cId", cId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

The problem is I do not see any thing in the html.So can any body tell me whats the mistake

Comment: are you setting the "parentList" attribute? and are you receing results in the methods? try to log or print out something to check if you get results from the database!

and probably you forgot a space after entityName: 
select p FROM "+entityName+" p WHERE category=default or category=client and p.cid="+cId;

Comment: @conFusl Is my query correct?

Comment: use p.category, and insert a space before " p WHERE.."

Comment: Can u provide the table structure of Parent?

and try to use query/the setparameter as follow: 
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + entityName + " p WHERE p.category='default' or p.category='client' and p.cid = :cId");
query.setParameter("cId", cId;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way (varchars in ''):

select p FROM "+entityName+" p WHERE p.category='default' or p.category='client' and p.cid=" +cId";

Comment: Thats just asking for an SQL injection :)

Comment: yeah, i know! In the comments above i added two lines howto work with Query and setparameter! the same would be possible with entityName, for sure! :)